# C++ Command not recognized after fork() and execl() call (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, exec, xdotool

I'm trying to create a program that can open a terminal browser and navigate through a website. It works fine up until the child process is called. The following error shows up

"xdotool: Unknown command:  search --onlyvisible --name Terminal windowactivate keydown Down"

I've tested the command in a separate terminal and it indeed works but it doesn't get recognized in my code. I get the feeling it might have to do with the fact that execl doesnt return back to main but I'm new to programming so I don't know for certain.

Heres the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

string thread;
cout << "website: ";
cin >> thread;

const char* xdo = "xdotool";
pid_t pid = fork();
string strThread = "" + thread;
string xdoCMD = " search --onlyvisible --name Terminal windowactivate keydown Down";

if (pid < 0) {
cout << "Process failed" << endl;
return 1;
} 
else if (pid == 0) {
execl("/usr/bin/xdotool", "xdotool", xdoCMD.c_str(), (char *) NULL);
}

else {
//  sleep(1);
execl("/usr/bin/elinks", "elinks", strThread.c_str(), (char *) NULL);
}
}
```

Comment: I think you need to read up more on [the `exec` family](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) of functions. The argument you pass is a *single* argument (all of the string you pass will be `argv[1]` in the program you execute, and `argc` will be equal to `2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[execl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) is calling [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (whose arguments go into the `main` of the executed program). They return only on failure.

So

```
execl("/usr/bin/xdotool", "xdotool", xdoCMD.c_str(), (char *) NULL);
```

is calling the `xdotool` program with two arguments, `xdotool` and `xdoCMD.c_str()` -as a *single* second argument.

You should split `xdoCMD.c_str()` into several pieces. Build an appropriate (`NULL` terminated!) array of `char*` from it, then call [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) on that.

In effect, you should mimic what the shell does. Perhaps you might even want [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (but you need to decide what kind of [expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) you want; beware perhaps of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)). See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

Don't forget to check against failure (of `fork`, `execvp` etc...)

BTW, both the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) (don't forget to compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -g`) and [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) are useful to find such a bug.